# When is it OK to not be "constructive"?

Tags: discussion

Are there an established general guidelines on the acceptability of non-constructive, negative "you can't possibly do that" answers?

When are they allowed?

Are they disliked or frowned upon?

Comment: Are you talking about meta? Or some other site? Can you provide some context?

Comment: You can't do that because of ... is very constructive, I would say.

Comment: @PeterMortensen Non "constructive" answers to programming problems "how do I do such and such with only such and such tools" when it isn't doable with exactly these tools.